# Getting column records from SQL server into excel dropdown list?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to get my second column in sql server table [Pursuant] column "Landowner" rows into a drop-down list in cell B2 in my excel file. This code I have only seems to get the first record from my DB table: Any ideas how to get all of the records?

```
Sub PopulateDropdownList()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim landownerNames As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tempRange As Range

    ' Define the connection string
    strConn = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=NICKS_LAPTOP;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=pursuant;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    ' Create a new connection object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    ' Open the connection
    conn.Open strConn

    ' Create a new recordset object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' Set a reference to the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' Set up a SQL query to retrieve distinct Landowner names from the SQL Server table
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Landowner FROM [Pursuant]"

    ' Execute the SQL query
    rs.Open strSQL, conn

    ' Concatenate Landowner names into a single string
    landownerNames = ""
    i = 0
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If i > 0 Then
            landownerNames = landownerNames & ","
        End If
        landownerNames = landownerNames & rs.Fields(0).Value
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ' Close the recordset
    rs.Close

    ' Close the connection
    conn.Close

    ' Clear existing data validation in cell B2
    ws.Range("B2").Validation.Delete

    ' Create a temporary range to hold the dropdown options
    Set tempRange = ws.Range("B2")

    ' Write the concatenated Landowner names to the temporary range
    tempRange.Value = Split(landownerNames, ",")

    ' Add data validation to cell B2 with the temporary range as the source
    With ws.Range("B2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & tempRange.Address
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I am trying to create a template where a user can go into cell b2 in excel, select a landowner name and then that'll do a lookup to the other relevant data from sql server, but I need to get this dropdown list to populate first

Comment: Just use `Formula1:=landownerNames`

Comment: @CDP1802 that populates the first landowner name again, and then throws an application defined error on 

        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _xlBetween, 
         Formula1:=landownerNames`

Comment: @CDP1802 Not sure why im getting the error because I see excel can populate 30k+ entries in a data validation list

Comment: How many distinct names in the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another sheet to hold the list (it could be hidden)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateDropdownList()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim strConn As String, strSQL As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Define the connection string
    strConn = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=NICKS_LAPTOP;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=pursuant;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    
    ' Create a new connection object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    ' Open the connection
    conn.Open strConn
  
    ' Set up a SQL query to retrieve distinct Landowner names from the SQL Server table
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Landowner FROM [Pursuant]"
  
    ' Execute the SQL query
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
       .Cells.Clear
       .Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset conn.Execute(strSQL)
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Close the connection
    conn.Close
    
    ' Set a reference to the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' Add data validation to cell B2 with the temporary range as the source
    With ws.Range("B2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$" & lastrow
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
   
End Sub
```